# zsh - Sort files expansion in MacOS Terminal like in Finder: numerically and case-insensitively

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh, sort

Is it possible in MacOS Terminal to have the sort order numerically and case-insensitively, almost like in Finder?
I'm on MacOS 14 Sonoma, using Terminal app with zsh 5.9 and oh-my-zsh.

I'm trying to execute some command line for all files in a specific folder.
Please compare:

| My desired sort order | MacOS Finder sort by name order |
| --- | --- |
| bar.jpg bar-2.jpg bar-10.jpg foo.jpg foo-1.jpg foo-2.jpg foo-10.jpg STA.jpg STA-3.jpg STA-20.jpg | bar-2.jpg bar-10.jpg bar.jpg foo-1.jpg foo-2.jpg foo-10.jpg foo.jpg STA-3.jpg STA-20.jpg STA.jpg |

The Finder way would be fine, but not ideal, as it leaves *foo.jpg* below *foo-1.jpg*

Here are commands I tried:

| for file in *; do echo $file; done | for file in *(n); do echo $file; done |
| --- | --- |
| STA-20.jpg STA-3.jpg STA.jpg bar-10.jpg bar-2.jpg bar.jpg foo-1.jpg foo-10.jpg foo-2.jpg foo.jpg | STA-3.jpg STA-20.jpg STA.jpg bar-2.jpg bar-10.jpg bar.jpg foo-1.jpg foo-2.jpg foo-10.jpg foo.jpg |

The latter brings in numerical sort order and is the closest I could get to Finder, but leaves uppercase *STA** files above lowercase *bar** ones.

I tried to use glob qualifier cause it looked like the simplest syntax, but if it's not achievable – please suggest other ways to execute commands on multiple files after sorting them the way I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will generate a sorted list similar to Finder's:

```bash
lc() { REPLY=$REPLY:l }
print -rl -- *(no+lc)
```

Output:

```
bar-2.jpg
bar-10.jpg
bar.jpg
foo-1.jpg
foo-2.jpg
foo-10.jpg
foo.jpg
STA-3.jpg
STA-20.jpg
STA.jpg
```

This adds the `o+` glob qualifier, which can execute shell code to supply a value for sorting that is different from the original file name. Here the code in the function `lc` changes the sorting filename to lowercase with the `:l` modifier, so that the sort is case-insensitive. Note that this does not change the displayed filename.

Comment: Thanks! Based on this I was able to reach what I defined as "My desired sort order":   `lc() { REPLY=${(L)REPLY%.*} }; print -rl -- *(no+lc)` – this changes the sorting filename to [lowercase without extension].

Comment: @DmitriiKuznetsov - Excellent solution. Apparently `.` sorts after numbers when using `(n)`, while 'nothing' sorts before. BTW, it turns out this also works: `print -rl -- *(noe.'REPLY=$REPLY:r:l'.)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use case-insensitive (`-f`) version sorting (`-V`) with `sort`:

```
cd <your directory>
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
  # <your command(s) accepting each filename here>
  printf "%q\n" "$filename"
done < <(find . -type f -print0 | sort -z -f -V)
```

Or more efficiently if your command(s) can slurp all filenames:

```
cd <your directory>
filenames=()
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename; do
  filenames+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find . -type f -print0 | sort -z -f -V)
# <your command(s) accepting all filenames (more efficient if possible)>
printf "%q\n" "${filenames[@]}"
```

These are safe, portable ways to execute commands for a list of filenames. Both output:

```
./bar.jpg
./bar-2.jpg
./bar-10.jpg
./foo.jpg
./foo-1.jpg
./foo-2.jpg
./foo-10.jpg
./STA.jpg
./STA-3.jpg
./STA-20.jpg
```